# How many instances of static class can we create?

Tags: java

Question from my interview: 
How many instances of static class can we create?

Correct answer: 1.

Can you explain me, why the correct anserw is 1?

Comment: Probably the question was not relative to static classes, but to static members.

Comment: Is the code the actual example that was part of the question? Also, I second Davide's comment: you probably misread the question.

Comment: Run a simple test to check if both are not null and not equal.

Answer (score 0):

A class can have static members and a static initialization block, which is very similar to the instantiated objects with their members and constructors.

The difference is, that there is only one static class and the static members only exist once, whereas, there may be any number of instantiated objects.

Calling the class an 'instance' is misleading at best. Looking at the Java documentation, there is always a clear distinction between classes and instances. So my guess is, that it is simply wrong.